# How can I access a SPI NAND Flash Memory in embedded Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, flash, serial, embedded-linux

I am a newbie with embedded Linux. I am using a Leon-Linux system on my evaluation board(Grmon GR712). I can compile the Linux kernel and build an image file via build-root.

I want to access an SPI NAND flash memory, IS37SML01G1 from userspace in Linux.

Assuming that the wire configuration for SPI in the evaluation board is OK, How can I access flash memory?

What should I change in my kernel configuration? There is not a specific driver for IS37SML01G1.

Comment: If you have to ask what to do, then you would be better off choosing a device that already has a Linux driver.  Otherwise you need to learn how to write a SPI protocol driver for your device that is compatible with the SPI NAND framework.  You could test with the **spidev** userspace driver, but that is not a longterm solution, unless you plan on providing everything (e.g. filesystem read & write) to access that chip.

Comment: @sawdust,  since this is an inheritance project(I joined later on), choosing a proper device is out of me, unfortunately.  I consider this as an opportunity to learn embedded Linux. Actually,I need a starting point (documentation, example etc) and to verify 3-ways that I have found to hookup a device in Linux.  1st - write a kernel code(driver) 2nd- Write a user-space code via spidev  3th- Enable Memory Technology Device(MTD) driver an get Linux to see as dev/mtd. I want to ask these 3 methods are valid?